# Can an Indian passport holder with a US F1 visa travel to Europe without a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, paperwork

I am an Indian holding a valid passport with a valid F1 (student) visa. I want to travel to Europe for my break. Can I travel there without applying for a Schengen visa? I have heard that US visa holders don't need a visa to travel to Europe. If so, is it applicable for F1 visa holders as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: How is it a duplicate? That question is about transiting, while the OP wants to visit Europe.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No. You will need a Schengen visa.

Holders of US visas are exempt, in certain cases, from the need to obtain a Schengen *transit* visa (see [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)) if they don't need to enter the Schengen area and simply need to change planes once within the zone, but that exemption does not extend to visitor visas.

Answer (score 13):

> I have heard that US visa holders don't need a visa to travel in Europe

Whoever told you that is **wrong**

To enter the Schengen Area, you must have a Schengen visa, and holding another country's visa, even from a non-Schengen EU country, does **not** exempt you.

Comment: Whoever told him that might have been right, but the message imprecisely stated or misunderstood, if "travel in Europe" was used in a context where it meant "transit through a European airport."

Comment: US _passport_ holders don't need a visa to my understanding.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not for visits, no, and for e.g. Germany not even for residence

Comment: @Coke That may have been the source of confusion here

Answer (score 0):

You cannot travel Europe with US visa but it will ease the process of getting Schengen visa for you.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you *do* need a Schengen VISA. You might have either misheard the person who told you, or they might have misspoke - what's true is that US *Passport* holders don't need a VISA to visit most (all?) Schengen nations.